# Extract the second last element in lists in a Panda Series

Tags: python, pandas

In a Panda Dataframe, there is a column of data that I want to extract the second last word of strings limited by '-', and put that into another column/series

sample data:

```
Serial_Code=pd.series([
    xxxx-myData1-xxx,
    xxxx-xxx-xx-myData2-x,
    MyData3-xxxxxxxx,
    x-MyData4-xxx,
])
```

As you can see the data I want to extract is always in the 2nd block from right delimited by dashes

I have used pandas.str.split to separate the string blocks

```
temp_series=df["Serial_Code"].str.split("-")
```

Now I have a series consists of lists of different lengths

```
temp_series=pd.Series([
    [xxxx,myData1,xxx],
    [xxxx,xxx,xx,myData1,x],
    [myData3,xxxxxxx],
    [x,myData4,xxx]
])
```

How do I get a list/series like this, without using loop to go through each row line by line?

```
final_series=([
    myData1, 
    myData2, 
    myData3, 
    myData4
])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `str` accessor

```
s.str.split('-').str[-2]
```

or

```
s.str.split('-').str.get(-2)
```

Both yields

```
0    myData1
1    myData2
2    MyData3
3    MyData4
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks! Both work every well! I'm not sure what str[-2] is and can't seem to be able to documentation on it. Is this a method under Pandas?

Comment: @JHsilver they're the same thing, but `[]` also allows for slicing ;}